# Sharepoint Open Page in New Tab not Window

Tags: sharepoint, tabs

I am working on a sharepoint page and want certain links to open in a new tab not a new window. I haven't seen any way to do this other than have server access or doing some invasive coding. I'm not sure of actual version of SP but think it's 2007.

IE version is v8

I checked code in edit mode and can see the target blank bit but as I said it opens in new window not tab.

Thanks

Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_blank` option for target param instructs the browser to open hyperlink in either new tab or window. But it depends on browser config or how link has been clicked on (middle click, ctrl+click or normal click) how the link would be opened (new window or new tab).

Comment: @andrewha so it's likely that it is the browser I am using (IE) and the way it is configured? I tried it in Chrome and it opened in new tab.

Comment: Do you have option Tools -> Internet Options -> Tabbed Browsing Settings -> Always open pop-ups in new tabs selected? If yes,  hyperlink with target="_blank" should open in a new tab.

Comment: Ok thanks however, ideally, I need this setting for all people opening a new window as a tab not just me, however I will set this in my own browser as it is a pain when it opens in a window.